# how to get the index of a reoccurring character in swift

Tags: swift, string

```
var string = "HELLO WOLRD"
```

I want to get all of the indexes of the letter "L" in the string (which in this case would be 2,3 and 8). How do I do that in swift?

Comment: It would be useful to show what you have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `enumerated()` along with `compactMap` like this:

```
var string = "HELLO WOLRD"

let indices = string.enumerated().compactMap { $0.element == "L" ? $0.offset : nil }
print(indices)
```

> ```
> [2, 3, 8]
> ```

**Explanation:**

1. `string.enumerated()` generates a sequence of tuple pairs where the first item is the offset of the character, and the second is the character.
2. The closure used by `compactMap` takes each tuple in turn and returns the offset of the character if it matches `L` or returns `nil` if it does not match.  `compactMap` leaves out the `nil` values and just returns the offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce(into:)` on the `enumerated` String.

```
let helloWorld = "HELLO WORLD"

let charsWithIndices = helloWorld.enumerated().reduce(into: [Character:[Int]](), { result, current in
    if result[current.element] != nil {
        result[current.element]!.append(current.offset)
    } else {
        result[current.element] = [current.offset]
    }
})

print(charsWithIndices)
```

> ["W": [6], "D": [10], "R": [8], "E": [1], "H": [0], " ": [5], "O": [4, 7], "L": [2, 3, 9]]

Or if you want to use the indices straight away for indexing your String, you can change make `charsWithIndices` of type `[Character:[String.Index]]`:

You can use `reduce(into:)` on the `enumerated` String.

```
let helloWorld = "HELLO WORLD"
let charsWithIndices = helloWorld.enumerated().reduce(into: [Character:[String.Index]](), { result, current in
    let index = helloWorld.index(helloWorld.startIndex, offsetBy: current.offset)
    if result[current.element] != nil {
        result[current.element]!.append(index)
    } else {
        result[current.element] = [index]
    }
})
```